# MPDF - Full page background based on page orientation

Tags: php, html, css, pdf, mpdf

I am using MPDF to generate a PDF from some data.

The general flow is as follows: I collect data from a database, I start output buffering, include a template, and clear the buffer and append the HTML to the PDF (calling $mpdf->AddPage when necessary). So far so good.

In my css, I have defined the body to have background-image: url('portrait-bg.png');, which works great.

Now, I want to add some pages that are in landscape format ($mpdf->AddPage(..., 'L');). That works too - but I cannot figure out how to set a different background for those pages (so that the image isn't stretched).

What I've tried:

- Setting an image directly on the pdf using $mpdf->Image (doesn't work, it counts as an actual image that content flows around, not as a background).
- Putting a  tag on the relevant page template, and then specifying a different background in my CSS (doesn't work, shows the original background - in fact, I don't seem to be able to select the body element at all in this manner!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after struggling with this for a long time, I was unable to find a good, clean way to do this - presumably due to shortcomings in MPDF.

In any case, the workaround I went with was using a style attribute on each body element that needed a special landscape background. It's not clean, it's not nice - but it seems to be the only way that works, unfortunately. Giving the body a class attribute and defining that in the linked CSS seems not to work (although I can't tell why - the MPDF docs claim to support this functionality, and it is how I set the standard background in the rest of the document).